# VBA Edit Userform Listbox (based on excel database) using Checkboxes and Textboxes

Tags: checkbox, textbox, listbox, userform

I've a database (5 column's and the row's are adaptive). This data is sorted as: Name, Surname, Date of Birth and Promotion year. 
I've also made an Userform based on a Listbox that can show this 4 informations.

Now i would like to edit this database using checkboxes and textboxes in the userform. 
I already made my userform but the problem persists in transfering the data of the userform (checkbox: true or false and textbox) into the database on the corresponding cell (of the right person).

Any idea how I should think or work on this? I already tried some stuff but i can't show up with a solution that can transfer AND the checkbox AND the Textbox information.

Greetz
[Userform Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xILbR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 5th column as A(status)

|Status|Name|Surname| DOB |Year|

Checkbx1 Data going to A(status)

Textbx1 Data going to B(Name)

Textbx2 Data going to C(Surname)

Textbx3 Data going to D(DOB)

Textbx4 Data going to E(Year)

**"You may assign this code to a command button"**

'Transfer of Data

If Form1.checkbox1=TRUE then

Shee1.Range("a:a").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select

Activecell.value="True"

else

Activecell.value="False"

end if

'transferring Name to B

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = StrConv(TextBox1, vbProperCase)

'transferring Surname to C

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = StrConv(TextBox2, vbProperCase)

'transferring DOB to D

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = StrConv(TextBox3, vbProperCase)

'transferring Year to E

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = StrConv(TextBox4, vbProperCase)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I as i Use a listbox, i'm able to select whatever name in that listbox. So working with an offset isn't always an option unless the corresponding cell to that name is selected. How should i put that into code?

Comment: Share screenshot of your userform, that will enable me to understand your requirement and data transfer

Comment: The screenshot has been added to the question (see link Userform Layout)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code for populating the list**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address).Name = "MyList"
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = Range("MyList").Columns.Count
    ListBox1.RowSource = "MyList"
End Sub
```

**Then use below code to Find and Select the data row in Sheet**

```
If ListBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
MsgBox " Select a row first !"
Exit Sub
Else
Cells.Find(What:=ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
```

**Then use Offset for transferring the data from UserForm to the Sheet**

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = UserForm1.Checkbox1.value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = UserForm1.optionbutton1.value
```